# Select Case statement, check for NULL, and/or empty string

Tags: null, crystal-reports

I am working with Crystal Reports 2016.  I have a formula with a `select case` statement, and I would like for one of those case's to check for `null`; my data has 4 conditions, and one of them is `null`.  However, to be thorough, I'd also like to check for an empty string `""`.  I have tried leaving a catchall statement at the end, but that does not detect `null`.  I have tried `isNull` and `is isNull`, and get an error about the wrong datatype (number expected) or that I need a comparison operator.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
select ({CRV_RoomAttributeValues.ScaledAnalogValue})
  case IsNull: "No Connection"
  case 0: "Offline"
  case 1: "Partially Online"
  case 2: "Online"
  default: "No connection";
```

This is the code I have now:

```
select ({CRV_RoomAttributeValues.ScaledAnalogValue})
  case is IsNull({CRV_RoomAttributeValues.ScaledAnalogValue}): "No Connection"
  case 0: "Offline"
  case 1: "Partially Online"
  case 2: "Online"
  default: "No connection";
```

I have seen several people on the net recommend testing for `null` first, because of the idiosyncrasies of Crystal Reports.

How do I test for `null` in a case statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up doing the following:

```
select ({CRV_RoomAttributeValues.ScaledAnalogValue})
  case 0: "Offline"
  case 1: "Partially Online"
  case 2: "Online"
  default: "No connection";
```

Answer (score 2):

The `select` statement executes straight comparisons, so the values of each case statement must always the same data type with your select variable/field. The `IsNull` is `boolean`, so what you are trying to do would work only if your `{CRV_RoomAttributeValues.ScaledAnalogValue}` was of `boolean` type.
I think that the easiest way (there are many ways, but in my opinion they are all weird so I won't include them here) to achieve your goal is to do the `null` value check explicitly at the beginning like this:

```
If(Isnull({CRV_RoomAttributeValues.ScaledAnalogValue})) Then
   "No Connection"
Else 
    Select {CRV_RoomAttributeValues.ScaledAnalogValue}
       case 0: "Offline"
       case 1: "Partially Online"
       case 2: "Online"
       default: "No connection";
```

in Crystal Syntax